# Nested flexbox grid not expanding

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I am having difficulty making nested flexboxes expand to fill their parent cells size. The two subcells should grow to have a height of 1/3 their parent cell however they are taking up as little space as they can. I'd like to fix this but have no idea how to.

```
<div class="grid">
<div class="cell blue">
    <p> This is a test grid, it is very tall <br> This is a test grid, it is very tall <br>This is a test grid, it is very tall <br>This is a test grid, it is very tall <br>This is a test grid, it is very tall <br>This is a test grid, it is very tall <br>This is a test grid, it is very tall <br>This is a test grid, it is very tall <br>This is a test grid, it is very tall <br>This is a test grid, it is very tall <br> </p>
</div>
<div class="cell green">
    <p> This is also a test grid, equally tall</p>
</div>
<div class="cell subgrid red">
    <div class="subcell">
        <p>This is a subcell, it should take up 33% if</p>
    </div>
    <div class="subcell">
        <p>this is another subcell, should be small and vertical</p>
    </div>
    <div class="subcell deepgrid">
        <div class="deepcell">
            <p>deep grid 1</p>
        </div>
        <div class="deepcell">
            <p>Deep grid 2</p>
        </div>
        <div class="deepcell">
            <p>Deep grid 3</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

```
.grid { display: flex; justify-content: center; text-align: center; }
.cell { flex: 1; }
.sub-grid { display: flex; }
.sub-cell { flex: 1 }
.deepgrid  {display: flex; }
.deepcell { flex: 1; }
.blue {background:blue;}
.green{background:green;}
.red{background:red;}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you used

```css
.sub-grid { display: flex; }
.sub-cell { flex: 1 }
```

However, in the HTML, you used the classes `subgrid` and `subcell`.

Moreover, you should also add `flex-direction` to arrange the subcells in a column.

Therefore, you should use

```
.subgrid {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
.subcell {
  flex: 1;
}
```

```css
.grid {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  text-align: center;
}
.cell {
  flex: 1;
}
.subgrid {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
.subcell {
  flex: 1
}
.deepgrid {
  display: flex;
}
.deepcell {
  flex: 1;
}
.blue {
  background: blue;
}
.green {
  background: green;
}
.red {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div class="cell blue">
    <p>This is a test grid, it is very tall
      <br>This is a test grid, it is very tall
      <br>This is a test grid, it is very tall
      <br>This is a test grid, it is very tall
      <br>This is a test grid, it is very tall
      <br>This is a test grid, it is very tall
      <br>This is a test grid, it is very tall
      <br>This is a test grid, it is very tall
      <br>This is a test grid, it is very tall
      <br>This is a test grid, it is very tall
      <br>
    </p>
  </div>
  <div class="cell green">
    <p>This is also a test grid, equally tall</p>
  </div>
  <div class="cell subgrid red">
    <div class="subcell">
      <p>This is a subcell, it should take up 33% if</p>
    </div>
    <div class="subcell">
      <p>this is another subcell, should be small and vertical</p>
    </div>
    <div class="subcell deepgrid">
      <div class="deepcell">
        <p>deep grid 1</p>
      </div>
      <div class="deepcell">
        <p>Deep grid 2</p>
      </div>
      <div class="deepcell">
        <p>Deep grid 3</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Wow I can't believe it was as simple as a missed hyphen! Thank you!